# A question about connected Hausdorff spaces.

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a Hausdorff space. Does there always exist a connected Hausdorff space H, which has a sub-space S that is homeomorphic to X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $X \times I$, where $I$ is the unit interval. collapse all points $(x, 0)$ to one point $x_0$ to get a space $CX$, called the [cone over $X$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_%28topology%29). This space is easily seen to be path-connected. It's Hausdorff if $X$ is Hausdorff. It contains $\{(x, 1) : x \in X\}$ as a subspace homeomorphic to $X$.

Comment: Thanks alot for this information. It looks as if your procedure would work for any topological space and not just Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: The cone isn't Hausdorff if $X$ isn't. Consider $X = \{a, b\}$ with the trivial topology. $CX$ doesn't contain open sets that separate $[a, 1]$ and $[b, 1]$.

Comment: I just meant that your procedure seems to show that any topological space can be topologically embedded in some connected topological space. The connected space need not be Hausdorff.

Comment: @GarabedGulbenkian Understood. Yes, that's correct.